# JSF2 CommandButton Action request params

Tags: jsf-2, request, parameter-passing

```
<h:commandButton value="Add Order"  action="#{orderBasket.addItems(param['orderItemId'])}"/>
```

I can't get the above to work...when you click on the button the param seems to get set to null. Is there a way around this?

Is there another way of passing the URL params into the action method? I'm using Spring EL resolver which limits my ability to pass in the parameters into beans as I'm not using faces-config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think you could use JSF better, a lot of problems would be much simpler. It looks that you are using JSF as a request/response framework, like Struts. JSF is an object oriented component framework, you should use it this way to get the best of it.

I'll try to solve your problem, but I'm missing some information on what you are doing.

If you have a list of books that you can order, let's say they are displayed in a datatable (you could use ui:repeat instead) :

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bookController.books}" var="book">

    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{book.title}" />
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <h:commandButton value="Add Order" action="#{orderBasket.addItems(book)}" />
    </h:column>

</h:dataTable>
```

In orderBasket backing bean, you simply take a Book (or whatever) as parameter. You don't need to handle the request/response cycle, certainly not in your views.

You can use f:ajax tag if you need to display that in your shopping cart immediately.

Let me know if you need more explanation (backing beans source or else).

Comment: Thanks but I prefer to control state through the URL to allow for bookmarking and navigation using browser back button. Any idea on the problem above? Cheers.

Comment: Maybe try a simple example app without Spring, to see if it's the culprit. Maybe use f:viewParam to get a real object on page load. Or PrettyFaces.